# How does returning by enable access control? (Java)

Tags: java

In Java, when you make a getter for a private field of class as follows(assume child is an ArrayList):

```
public ArrayList getChild() {
    return this.child;
}
```

you return a reference to the private field "name" (which means the ArrayList can be modified using that reference??) In C++, this same kind of code would return a copy, which would leave the object's field unharmed if that copy were manipulated.

Can you modify the private member by calling this method and then modifying the returned ArrayList reference? If yes, how does having a getter in a language like Java control access, then? And what is the proper way to write a getter that will protect the private members?

Comment: `And what is the proper way to write a getter that will protect the private members?` Depends what your definition of `protect` is. If it is "don't let anyone access it", then you wouldn't provide a getter. If it is don't let caller change it, then make the object returned by the getter immutable.

Comment: You might want to use a more realistic example, btw - `ArrayList<int>` isn't valid Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> you return a reference to the private field "name"

Well, not quite. You return the current *value* of the `child` field. It's important to understand that that's not the same as somehow returning a reference to the field itself. After the method has returned, any changes to the field (e.g. setting it to null, or making it refer to a different list) will *not* be seen by the method caller. It's important to differentiate between the field, the reference (which is the value of the field) and the object that the reference refers to.

> How does having a getter in a language like Java control access, then?

It doesn't, directly.

> And what is the proper way to write a getter that will return a copy?

That depends on the type. If you use immutable types, you don't need to copy anyway :)

For collections, you could potentially create a read-only *view* over the original collection - but then the caller will still see changes to the original collection. Or you can just explicitly create your own copy, e.g.

```
return new ArrayList<>(child);
```

Comment: "After the method has returned, any changes to the field (e.g. setting it to null, or making it refer to a different list) will not be seen by the method caller."

But any changes made by the caller will be seen by the object?

Comment: @user3427072: Changes made to the *object* will be seen - but nothing the caller does will change the value of the *field*. It will still refer to the same object as before... even if that object has its contents changed. (It's important to understand that the value of the field isn't an object, it's just a reference.)

Comment: I have read some other questions about pass by value vs. pass by reference in Java in the context of passing parameters to functions. I understand how Java passes by value in that context. Is the same principle at play here?

Comment: @user3427072: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to protect your objects, then make your object immutable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html